# Django how to change the admin panel template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to change what is displayed when I click on a model in the django admin. For example if I have the model `Book` and then I go into the admin panel and click book, it will give me all the fields that I created the model with.

But I want to edit that page that shows all that data. For example, if I click on the "Book" model in the admin panel and see my fields to edit, I want to put another bit of fields on the bottom from another model. Or maybe I want to put like a "Similar Books" list. Is it possible to edit this page?

Comment: You'll have to override [`ModelAdmin.change_view`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view)  for this model.

Comment: I am having a look at it but I am not understanding the example that it provides. Could add_view be what I am after?

Answer (score 0):

Admin customization information is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/). You can do stuff like `list_display` or `fieldsets` etc.